# Work with serial port in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

i am working with serial port in my WPF application,
and there is many errors like "not enough quota to process this command" in the log file.

This source i think with problem. Where is my mistake?

```
void barcodeSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string code = barcodeSerialPort.ReadLine();

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
        {                
            if (new DateTime(model.ComebackDate.Year, model.ComebackDate.Month, model.ComebackDate.Day) > DateTime.Now)
            {
                new WndMessage("Date time error...").ShowDialog();
                Switcher.Switch(new MainMenu());
                return;
            }

            // ...............
        });
```

---

```
10.01.2013 10:05:08 - Exception on UI Thread (Dispatcher)
Exception message - There is not enough quota to process this command
Source - WindowsBase
StackTrace -    at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.PostMessage(HandleRef hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowSettings(Boolean enableRenderTarget, Nullable`1 channelSet)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowPos(IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
TargetSite -Void PostMessage(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr)
InnerException.Message - NULL
```

Comment: Post a detailed error message, with the stack trace etc. Quota doesn't seem a likely problem with a Serial port.

Answer (score 0):

The data received event will be fired within it's own thread and by calling `Dispatcher.Invoke()` you call everytime this event is fired back into the gui thread and within that method you're going to call a `ShowDialog()` which will suspend till this dialog is closed, which will suspend your dispatcher, which will suspend your data receiving thread.

So to really solve this problem you have to decouple the data receiving and the gui tasks. Within the data received event simply put the received data into some kind of list, queue, etc and nothing more. Within the gui thread you regularly take a look into this list, queue (maybe by using a timer) and act on what you're getting.

**Beware:** If you need to manipulate the list, queue from multiple threads (e.g. add item in data received event, remove item in gui timer) you should take a look at the [`Concurrent`-namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) and also think about the usage of the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) or [ReactiveExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

Comment: Ok, i will try,
 but i thought that there is more simple and elegant way to solve such problems

Comment: @Бахрам Ходжаев: Using TPL and Rx are the elegant ways. Wait till i forget: In .Net 4.5 and VS2012 you could also use [async, await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

try using BeginInvoke from dispatcher class insteed of invoke method. this invoke method invokes on the same thread which causes this error. and beginInvoke methods will dispatch the object into UI Thread Queue which will work fine for this.

try using this.

```
 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
        {                
            if (new DateTime(model.ComebackDate.Year, model.ComebackDate.Month, model.ComebackDate.Day) > DateTime.Now)
            {
                new WndMessage("Date time error...").ShowDialog();
                Switcher.Switch(new MainMenu());
                return;
            }

            // ...............
        });
```